# Dagster is detecting my code but not my sensors?

Tags: dagster

I have a simple local dagster project. One of its files is as follows:

```py
from dagster import asset, Definitions, build_asset_reconciliation_sensor, AssetSelection

group_name = 'for_testing'

@asset(group_name=group_name)
def hello():
    return 'Hello'

@asset(group_name=group_name)
def loud_hello(hello):
    return hello.upper()

update_sensor = build_asset_reconciliation_sensor(
    name="update_sensor", asset_selection=AssetSelection.assets(hello, loud_hello)
)

defs = Definitions(assets=[hello, loud_hello], sensors=[update_sensor])
```

I am running dagit locally, and I can see and materialize the assets (`hello` & `loud_hello`)

But:

- Can't see the sensor in dagit
- The sensor is not working (loud_hello does not update when I update hello)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in the `__init__.py` of the dagster project.

I had created the project a few months back and it the `__init__.py` file was

```py
from .repository import my_dagster_project
```

Where `repository.py` contains:

```
from dagster import load_assets_from_package_module, repository
from my_dagster_project import assets

@repository
def my_dagster_project():
     return [load_assets_from_package_module(assets)]
```

I changed `__init__.py` to

```py
from .repository import defs
```

Where `defs` was is defined in `repository.py` as:

```py
from dagster import Definitions, load_assets_from_package_module
from my_dagster_project import assets

all_assets = load_assets_from_package_module(assets)

defs = Definitions(
    assets=all_assets,
    schedules=[assets.dg_test_schedule.update_job_schedule],
)
```

in `repository.py`